# Can I use the Apple watch as an individual device without the iPhone?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-5

In my case, I need to make an in-house communication system using Apple watches (without iPhones) There I'm planning to use UDP or TCP protocol for voice communication. 
And is it can able to receive a notification without iPhone?

Comment: [Why repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320152/can-i-use-apple-watch-as-an-individual-device)?  You have world wide audience, and not every one comes online at the same time, so it might take time to get an answer (if there is one)

Comment: read first before comment, in this case, use apple watch only

Comment: I did and I’m still scratching my head over the double post

Comment: As I commented on your other question, a watch needs to be paired with a phone for it to work.  You can't send notifications directly to a watch. You send them to the phone and the phone shows them on the watch if the phone is locked/sleeping.  Although multiple watches can be paired with a phone only one is active at a time, so notifications to that phone only go to one watch at a time. A watch app cannot listen for incoming TCP or UDP connections/packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

watch OS 6 and above now allows independent Watch apps.

Check out it's WWDC: [Creating Independent Watch Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/208)

> watchOS 6 enables a whole new level of watchOS experiences by allowing
>   fully independent apps and apps built just for Apple Watch, and by
>   bringing the App Store to Apple Watch. Discover how to leverage the
>   power of many iOS frameworks and technologies, now on watchOS, to
>   create fully independent experiences on Apple Watch.

---

For lower versions, an Apple Watch app installs as an extension to an iPhone app. You would need an iPhone to access the AppStore to install an iPhone app, which provides an extension app to the Apple Watch.

In this case, you can create a simply, bare minimum iPhone app but with a complex Apple Watch app extension.

Comment: thanks, can I know it can be able to receive a notification without iPhone?

Comment: @Hominda This answer is/was correct for watchOS 5.  This is changing with watchOS6 - I suggest you start here - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/208/

Comment: @Hominda I've updated my answer for watch OS 6. Your minimum app target should be watch OS 6 in this case